# How to solve android sdk error in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

The following SDK components were not installed:
Sources for Android 34 and Android Emulator

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Sources for Android 34: Read timed out.

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Android Emulator: Read timed out.
```

I tried reinstalling android studio and also tried connecting android emulator with VS Code but it was of no help.